Ansible - Remove double quotes from a key in list array
I have the below output array and I need to remove the double quotes in front of channelId alone.

TASK [Print updated channel array] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": [
{
"channelId": "f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01"
},
{
"channelId": "06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8"
},
{
"channelId": "de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32"
}
]
}

Expected Output:

[
{
channelId: "f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01"
},
{
channelId: "06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8"
},
{
channelId: "de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32"
}
]


Basically, what you are asking is for Ansible to produce you an invalid JSON, which it obviously cannot do. What are you trying to achieve here? What is your end goal?

For those who want to write Ansible code, it's beneficial to understand JSON vs. YAML, I think.

What you see is valid JSON format. In JSON all keys and most of the values are quoted. For example, the same list in YAML
shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    channel:
       - channelId: f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01
       - channelId: 06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8
       - channelId: de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ channel }}"

will be displayed by default in JSON
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml 
  ...
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "channelId": "f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01"
        },
        {
            "channelId": "06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8"
        },
        {
            "channelId": "de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32"
        }
    ]
}

You can ask Ansible to display YAML
shell> ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_RESULT_FORMAT=yaml ansible-playbook pb1.yml 
  ...
ok: [localhost] => 
    msg:
    -   channelId: f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01
    -   channelId: 06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8
    -   channelId: de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32

See
shell> ansible-doc -t callback ansible.builtin.default

Before you decide to "remove" the quotes, you must find out whether the quotes are part of the strings. For example,
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    channel:
       - channelId: f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01
       - channelId: 06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8
       - channelId: de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          item.channelId: {{ item.channelId }}
          item.channelId[0]: {{ item.channelId[0] }}
          item.channelId[-1]: {{ item.channelId[-1] }}
      loop: "{{ channel }}"

gives
shell> ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_RESULT_FORMAT=yaml ansible-playbook pb2.yml 
  ...
ok: [localhost] => (item={'channelId': 'f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01'}) => 
    msg: |-
        item.channelId: f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01
        item.channelId[0]: f
        item.channelId[-1]: 1
ok: [localhost] => (item={'channelId': '06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8'}) => 
    msg: |-
        item.channelId: 06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8
        item.channelId[0]: 0
        item.channelId[-1]: 8
ok: [localhost] => (item={'channelId': 'de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32'}) => 
    msg: |-
        item.channelId: de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32
        item.channelId[0]: d
        item.channelId[-1]: 2

You can see that there are no quotes in the strings. This is also valid for the JSON format. You can test it by putting channel in JSON format into the playbooks. The results will be the same.
Note, that JSON is a subset of YAML. This means a valid JSON is also valid YAML. As a result, in Ansible, you can use JSON instead of YAML if you want to.
Any "mixed" formats are also valid. For example,
  channel:
     - {channelId: f35ead0f-8252-4975-9055-5d050161da01}
     - {channelId: 06f3466f-f894-4555-8ba6-7283e219b8e8}
     - {channelId: de26fe02-a688-40fb-b580-46902c240e32}

When unsure test it in YAML Lint
